# Is it possible to open a web browser and interact on simulator when running xamarin ui tests

Tags: c#, xamarin, uitest

During my test I need to login to the app. When in a certain mode the app requires a one time password. This is created for testers on a webpage that is periodically updated with new codes. Is it possible to open a browser window and interact with it and the app in a Xamarin UI Test.

Example :

```
app.Login(username, password);
app.MenuNavigation(MenuItems.PrivatePage);
app.EnterAccessCode(code); 
//This is where I would need to enter the code from webpage.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If that browser is embedded inside your app through a webview or something else, the answer is yes. Otherwise no.

Comment: The webpage is not embedded into the app it would be opening a browser like safari or chrome that I was trying to do. Thanks for you response.